# ¿como puedo sacar los valores de un array python?

Tags: python

Estoy recién comenzando en el mundo python y quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar a sacar los valores de esta lista

```
array([[nan,'[]',"['hola']","['como']","['estas']"]])
```

Había pensado recorrerlo pero no lo permite por el elemento nan y no logro eliminarlo previamente para poder recorrerlo,

Si me pudieran ayudar les agradecería mucho.

Comment: Esa lista es demasiado extraña como explico en mi respuesta. Quizás deberías explicar para qué necesitas esto porque a lo mejor ya está mal el planteamiento inicial. Una lista como esa no debería existir :-)

Answer (score 2):

Es una pregunta bien extraña... me explico.

Python, de forma nativa, no tiene el tipo `array`, ni tampoco tiene el símbolo `nan` para indicar "Not a number". Ambas cosas son extensiones disponibles en el módulo `numpy`. Por tanto entiendo que estás usando ese módulo aunque no lo mencionas.

Tu código se ejecuta sin errores de sintaxis (lo que no quiere decir que sea correcto conceptualmente, luego te cuento), sin más que añadir el `import` adecuado:

```
from numpy import array, nan

a = array([[nan,'[]',"['hola']","['como']","['estas']"]])
```

Ahora bien el hecho de que sintácticamente sea correcto, no quiere decir que estés haciendo algo correcto o siquiera lógico.

Para empezar, la lista que le pasas a `array` tiene un solo elemento, que es otra lista (pues tras el primer `[` se abre otro `[` que no se cierra hasta el final). Es decir, el array que se creará tiene dos dimensiones, si bien en una de esas dimensiones sólo tiene un elemento. Puede comprobarse con:

```
print(a.shape)
(1, 5)
```

Que quiere decir que el array tiene una fila, y 5 columnas.

Para seguir, los elementos de esa fila son cada uno de un tipo diferente. Esta no es la forma en la que se supone que debas usar un `array` de `numpy`. Estos arrays están diseñados para cálculo matricial numérico eficiente y se supone que todos los elementos del array son del mismo tipo, generalmente un número de coma flotante.

En tu caso en cambio tienes un primer elemento que es un `nan` (que es un tipo particular de número que significa "no es un número válido", que puede aparecer como consecuencia de algunas operaciones matemática), pero los restantes elementos son todos strings, pues van entre comillas.

Incluso como string son raros, porque el contenido de cada uno de esos strings vuelve a tener dentro corchetes, como si quisieras que fueran a su vez otras listas. Pero no lo son, porque van entre comillas, son meras cadenas.

Dicho todo lo cual, y a pesar de lo extraño y retorcido de tu ejemplo, **no hay razón para que no puedas imprimir los elementos**. El hecho de que el primero sea `nan` no afecta a su impresión, sólo te daría problemas si intentaras alguna operación matemática con él.

Para imprimir `a` tienes varias opciones:

- Dejar que lo imprima `numpy`. Basta hacer `print(a)` y él elige una representación apropiada, que sería:

  ```
  array([['nan', '[]', "['hola']", "['como']", "['estas']"]], dtype='<U32')
  ```
- Iterar sobre el array. Cada iteración te devuelve una fila que puedes imprimir directamente:

  ```
  for fila in a:
      print("Fila: ", fila)
  ```

  ```
  Fila:  ['nan' '[]' "['hola']" "['como']" "['estas']"]
  ```
- Iterar por el array y después iterar por cada elemento de la fila, para imprimir separadamente cada elemento:

  ```
  for fila in a:
      print("Fila:")
      for elemento in fila:
          print("  Elemento:", elemento)
  ```

  ```
  Fila:
      Elemento: nan
      Elemento: []
      Elemento: ['hola']
      Elemento: ['como']
      Elemento: ['estas']
  ```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: ¿te sirvió? Tengo curiosidad sobre tu problema real :-)

Answer (score 1):

En el código hay dos detalles.

1- No existen los array en python, se usan las listas []
Ejemplo:

```
lista_super = ['platano', 'manzanas', 'peras']
```

para acceder al primer elemento lista_super[0] como un arreglo.

2-Si entras nan solamente va a saltar un error de que nan no esta definido, si te refieres al valor vacío en python es None.

Espero te sirva